# How can I get hilbert marginal spectrum with matlab2018a?

Tags: matlab

I can implement eemd and hht on my signal data to obtain imf and hilbert spectrum with matlab2018a. However, i don't kown how to get hilbert marginal spectrum.

I had found some codes, but they are not suitable for my matlab version I think. The codes I found contain "hhspectrum" and "toimage" which the matlab2018a cannot recognize. 
The codes I found are as following:

```
[A,f,tt]=hhspectrum(imf);
[E,tt,Cenf]=toimage1(A,f);
disp_hhs(E);  
E=flipud(E);
NN=size(E,1);
for k=1:size(E,1)
    bjp(k)=sum(E(k,:))*1/Fs;
end
ff=(0:NN-1)/NN*(Fs/2);
figure(3);
plot(ff,bjp);
% plot(Cenf(1,:)*Fs,bjp); 
xlabel('Frequency / Hz');
ylabel('Amplitude');
```

And I also found the hhspectrum.m and toimage.m, but there are some errors when I immplement them and i do not how to fix them.

**I have implemented my signal data using the codes like this:**

```
imf=eemd(globalsignal,3,100);

[hs,f,T]=hht(imf,fs);
```

**and got the imf and hilbert spectrum hs.**

My qustion is **how can I get hilbert maiginal spectrum based on imf,hs,emd,and hht? In addition, how can I plot 3D figure with time,frequency and energy?** I only kown The marginal spectrum is obtained by integrating the Hilbert spectrum, but how to integrate?

Please help me, thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have to use the codes with old matlab version. But now I have got marginal hilbert spectrum. So, if you have a better answer about marginal hilbert spectrum with new matlab version, please leave you words. 
Sincerely thanks!